# How do read and writes work with a manager in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, synchronization, multiprocessing-manager

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm having trouble understanding how managers work in python.

Let's say I have a manager that contains a dictionary to be shared across all processes. I want to have just one process writing to the dictionary at a time, while many others read from the dictionary.

1. Can this happen concurrently, with no synchronization primitives or will something break if read/writes happen at the same time?
2. What if I want to have multiple processes writing to the dictionary at once - is that allowed or will it break (I know it could cause race conditions, but could it error out)?
3. Additionally, does a manager process each read and write transaction in a queue like fashion, one at a time, or does it do them all at once?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: 1. simultaneous read/writes are usually a problem - which is why mutex/semaphores/etc. exist. 2. use a mutex so only one simultaneous writer is allowed - in some cases (changing more than one variable, etc.) you may want to exclude reading while writes are occurring as well. 3. not sure about the specifics of how managers are implemented

Comment: I appreciate the response, but my questions is specifically about python managers, and what will happen if two processes modify the shared object that the manager holds (or if one reads while the other writes). I am wondering if managers under the hood handle read/writes one at a time.

Comment: It looks like from a long time ago, this answer would seem to indicate that reads and writes only happen one at a time, but loading the result happens concurrently? This is for value though, I wonder about dictionary. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you write to the dictionary, i.e. whether the operation is *atomic* or not:

```py
my_dict[some_key] = 9 # this is atomic
my_dict[some_key] += 1 # this is not atomic
```

So creating a new key and updating a an existing key as in the first line of code above are atomic operations. But the second line of code are really multiple operations equivalent to:

```py
temp = my_dict[some_key]
temp = temp + 1
my_dict[some_key] = temp
```

So if two processes were executing `my_dict[some_key] += 1` in parallel, they could be reading the same value of `temp = my_dict[some_key]` and incrementing `temp` to the same new value and the net effect would be that the dictionary value only gets incremented once. This can be demonstrated as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Lock

def init_pool(the_lock):
    global lock
    lock = the_lock

def worker1(d):
    for _ in range(1000):
        with lock:
            d['x'] += 1

def worker2(d):
    for _ in range(1000):
        d['y'] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    with Manager() as manager, \
    Pool(4, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(lock,)) as pool:
        d = manager.dict()
        d['x'] = 0
        d['y'] = 0
        # worker1 will serialize with a lock
        pool.apply_async(worker1, args=(d,))
        pool.apply_async(worker1, args=(d,))
        # worker2 will not serialize with a lock:
        pool.apply_async(worker2, args=(d,))
        pool.apply_async(worker2, args=(d,))
        # wait for the 4 tasks to complete:
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
{'x': 2000, 'y': 1162}
```

**Update**

As far as serialization, goes:

The `BaseManager` creates a server using by default a socket for Linux and a named pipe for Windows. So essentially every method you execute against a managed dictionary, for example, is pretty much like a remote method call implemented with message passing. This also means that the server could also be running on a different computer altogether. **But, these method calls are not serialized; the object methods themselves must be thread-safe because each method call is run in a new thread.**

The following is an example of creating our own managed type and having the server listening for requests possibly from a different computer (although in this example, the client is running on the same computer). The client is calling `increment` on the managed object 1000 times across two threads, but the method implementation is not done under a lock and so the resulting value of `self.x` when we are all done is not 1000. Also, when we retrieve the value of `x` twice concurrently by method `get_x` we see that both invocations start up more-or-less at the same time:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Event, Thread, get_ident
import time

class MathManager(BaseManager):
    pass

class MathClass:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x

    def increment(self, y):
        temp = self.x
        time.sleep(.01)
        self.x = temp + 1

    def get_x(self):
        print(f'get_x started by thread {get_ident()}', time.time())
        time.sleep(2)
        return self.x

    def set_x(self, value):
        self.x = value

def server(event1, event2):
    MathManager.register('Math', MathClass)
    manager = MathManager(address=('localhost', 5000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    manager.start()
    event1.set() # show we are started
    print('Math server running; waiting for shutdown...')
    event2.wait() # wait for shutdown
    print("Math server shutting down.")
    manager.shutdown()

def client():
    MathManager.register('Math')
    manager = MathManager(address=('localhost', 5000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    manager.connect()
    math = manager.Math()
    pool = ThreadPool(2)
    pool.map(math.increment, [1] * 1000)
    results = [pool.apply_async(math.get_x) for _ in range(2)]
    for result in results:
        print(result.get())

def main():
    event1 = Event()
    event2 = Event()
    t = Thread(target=server, args=(event1, event2))
    t.start()
    event1.wait() # server started
    client() # now we can run client
    event2.set()
    t.join()

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
Math server running; waiting for shutdown...
get_x started by thread 43052 1629375415.2502146
get_x started by thread 71260 1629375415.2502146
502
502
Math server shutting down.
```

Comment: I understand the race condition. My question is more so about how the manager handles this under the hood. Does this mean it processes all reads and writes one at a time?

Comment: Ah, this explains it. Thank you!